# Unlimited choices in BASH case statement

Tags: bash

Consider this simple bash snippet:

```
case $OPTION in
  1)
    IMAGE=${options[0]%.tar}
    ;;
  2)
    IMAGE=${options[1]%.tar}
    ;;
  3)
    IMAGE=${options[2]%.tar}
    ;;
  4)
    IMAGE=${options[3]%.tar}
    ;;
  *)
    echo "invalid option"
    exit 1
esac
```

In my real script the numbers goes up to 30. Which makes it pretty long.
Can I somehow specify cases with a variable?

Something like this:

```
case $OPTION in
  $i)
    IMAGE=${options[$(($i-1))]%.tar}
```

Any pointer is much appreciated.

Comment: Well, what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can match against multiple patterns in a single clause:

```
case $OPTION in
    1|2|3:
       echo "$OPTION is one, two or three"
       ;;
esac
```

if this is still too much typing for you, you can use some simple pattern matching:

```
case $OPTION in
  # the following matches
  #  - single-digit numbers 0-9
  #  - two-digit numbers starting with either 1 or 2
  #  - the number 30
  [0-9]|[12][0-9]|30)
     IMAGE=${options[$(($OPTION-1))]%.tar}
     ;;
  *)
     echo "invalid option" 1>&2
     exit 1
esac
```

Answer (score 3):

Oh my, DRY:

```
if (( 1 <= OPTION && OPTION <= 30 )); then
    IMAGE=${options[OPTION-1]%.tar}
else
    echo "invalid option" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `1 < OPTION && OPTION < 30)`??

Comment: let evalautes arithmetic and octal as well though so things like `034` will be valid although i find it highly unlikely that that is desired by OP.

Comment: @123, we can fix that by using `10#$OPTION` instead

Comment: @umlaute, I think the question is pretty clear that 1 and 30 should be included

Comment: @glennjackman That would solve octal but it would still evaluate arithmetic like `7-1`, `8+2*2-4`, etc. I realise they are unlikely but still, i don't really like let in if statements because of that.

Comment: @glennjackman DoH! i somehow head the logic reversed. sorry for the noise.